# Nav bar sticking to the top

Tags: jquery, html, css

I used code from [Here](http://www.jay-han.com/2011/11/10/simple-smart-sticky-navigation-bar-with-jquery/) to use get a navbar to stick at the top.  This works fine, but when I add my actual navigation div, the nav bar is set about 20 pixels from the top and jumps back up to the top when you scroll.

I added this under the nav:

```
<div id="navbar">
<ul id="navlist">
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Prints</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Services</a></li>   
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Any idea why as soon as I add a list or div within the nav it messes eveything up?
http://jsfiddle.net/x4GQ5/3/

Comment: You probably have a margin on your ul. Hard to tell without posting some css or a fiddle would be better.

Comment: Please post some CSS code

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/x4GQ5/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include `overflow: hidden;` on `ul#nav` as it has floated descendants (its height collapses as result) and you need to remove the default margin on your `<ul>`. You should also look into including a [CSS reset](http://www.cssreset.com/) so you can avoid the default browser style rules.

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Adrift/x4GQ5/4/)

Answer (score 1):

You would need to set a `margin: 0` for your ul#nav.

```
ul#nav  {
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 2em;
  margin: 0;    
}
```

Comment: Also like @Adrift mentioned you should consider using a css reset.